# Calculating price with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

So I have something like this -

3 seasons and each differs with prices, so for example
Season 1 -
April 1 - May 30, the prices will be 20$
October 1 - December 15, the prices will be 10$
June 1 - August 1, the prices will be 50$

All prices are calculated for one day, so for example if I rent something between June 1 and August 1 for 5 days the price will be 250$.

I need to show it on Input field window as value, but well, I'm not sure how to create that with Jquery.

I'm taking out prices with php, and assigning it to the value $price. (people can choose from select, what they want to reservate, the prices for each item differs), when they select car, nothing at first shows up, but after that they can select date, and when they do that, the price shows up. Hope you understood what I ment.

Comment: What have you got which isn't working?

Comment: Well, basically I currently have only html, now I'm working on php to get out the prices and assign them to variables.

Comment: @ user1184909 Assigning the php value to a javascript variable is as follows: var $myJqueryVar = "<? myPhpVar /?>"; . You can leave the quotation signs if the value should be a numeric one.

Comment: Okay, I know that, but I'm not sure how to do the calculation, when they choose a item and a date, so it go through, find automatically between which season it is, and then counts the days and multiplies them with the price of car in that season.

Comment: What do you want to do with php and jQuery ? Where is the interface ?!

Comment: Well, as i said, i have a form with ability to select item and date, if the date is between the dates I gave you above, the price for one day, will be the price above, and then people can see before pressing submit button how much everything will cost.

Comment: I think you are having dropdown to select date?
find out month from date and from hidden field value find the price for that month 
just multiply price and days and display it

Comment: for no of days you are having 2 dropdown(start date,end date) ?

Comment: and date also in which format ,as in 3 dropdown for year,month and day or dropdown with y-m-d(eg.2012-02-08)?

Comment: Yes, i have start date and end date, and formats are d-m-y, for example year - for($i = 2012; $i < 2020; $i++) { <option value="$i">$i</otpion> } for($d = 1; $d < 32; $d++) { <option value="$d">$d</option> } for($m = 1; $m < 13; $m++) { <option value="$m">$m</option> } and the same for return dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all though all cases are not handled in this example , but u will get an idea to calculate the price

```
$('select').live("change",function(){
                month_price = $('#start_date_month').val();

                price = ($('#start_date_month option[value="'+month_price+'"]').attr('price'));

                startday = $('#start_date_day').val();

                endday = $('#end_date_day').val();
                end_month = $('#end_date_month').val();
                if(endday > 15 && end_month==12)
                {
                    price = $('#start_date_month option[value="1"]').attr('price');
                }

                days = endday - startday;
                $('#price').val(days*price);

            });
```

and html code will be like this

```
<select name="start_date_day" id="start_date_day" >
                <?php
                for ($d = 1; $d < 32; $d++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="start_date_month" id="start_date_month">
                <?php
                for ($m = 1; $m < 13; $m++) {
                    if ($m == 4 || $m == 5)
                        echo '<option value="' . $m . '" price=20>' . $m . '</option>';
                    elseif ($m == 6 || $m == 7)
                        echo '<option value="' . $m . '" price=50>' . $m . '</option>';
                    elseif ($m == 10 || $m == 11 || $m == 12)
                        echo '<option value="' . $m . '" price=10>' . $m . '</option>';
                    else
                        echo '<option value="' . $m . '" price=5>' . $m . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="start_date_year" id="start_date_year">
                <?php
                for ($i = 2012; $i < 2020; $i++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</otpion> ';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="end_date_day" id="end_date_day">
                <?php
                for ($d = 1; $d < 32; $d++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="end_date_month" id="end_date_month">
                <?php
                for ($m = 1; $m < 13; $m++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $m . '">' . $m . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="end_date_year" id="end_date_year">
                <?php
                for ($i = 2012; $i < 2020; $i++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</otpion> ';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>
```

Comment: Will test it later today. I saw that you have if statement in Jquery about days, and I remembered, that I will need check, since people could take items not only in one season, but in two seasons, and then it means the prices could change. For example they could take item from August 20 till September 10, which means that 11 days will be with High season price and 10 days will be with Low season price, can you give me an example of something like that too, if it's not included?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have shown one handled case for month of dec before 15 is start date and end date is after 15 so what will be the price

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').live("change",function(){
                month_price = $('#start_date_month').val();

                price = ($('#start_date_month option[value="'+month_price+'"]').attr('price'));

                startday = $('#start_date_day').val();

                endday = $('#end_date_day').val();
                end_month = $('#end_date_month').val();
                if(startday <15 && endday > 15 && month_price == 12 && end_month==12){
                    enddateprice = $('#start_date_month option[value="1"]').attr('price');
                    actualprice = ((16-startday)*price) + ((endday-16)*enddateprice);
                }
                else if(endday > 15 && end_month==12)
                {
                     days = endday - startday;
                    price = $('#start_date_month option[value="1"]').attr('price');
                    actualprice = days*price;
                }else{
                     days = endday - startday;
                     actualprice = days*price;
                }


                $('#price').val(actualprice);

            });
```